# Ajax post compatible with localhost wamp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to perfrom a simple POST function with Ajax on my localhost WAMP server.
I have the following code :

```
function fill_table()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {              
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {       
                document.getElementById("done_by").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;                                  
            }
        }
        alert(xmlhttp.statusText);

        xmlhttp.open('POST', '../functions/ajax/fill_progress.php');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("id_case=" + id_case);
        alert("posted good !");
    }
```

And here's my fill_progress.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo("test");
?>
```

And I have a `<span id="done_by"> </span>` in my html code.

So the code is simple but my post is not working when I tried to debug with firebug and alert(xmlhttp.status). I haven't any network traffic concerning the POST from Ajax. And I get the result code **0** which is most probably a mistake of rights or path. But it isn't, I tried the same code with a GET method and it works fine !

So I think that the problem is the following code

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

I think the www-form-urlencoded expect an URL like www.xxx.yyy but I work with localhost/.../.../...

Is it possible that this is a part of the solution ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: "I think the www-form-urlencoded expect an URL" — It does not.

Comment: Double check your URL, sometimes it happens that your not sending the information to the right location of the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **full path** instead of (*../smthg/random.php*) and it works.